# Private message with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, chat, messenger

I am building a simple private chat app with laravel and vue js.

I have a messages table with a column : `id/sender_id/receiver_id and body`

my main problem is fetching the users from the messages table. so if sender_id 1 has sent the message to receiver_id 2 then In the sender dashboard, I want to display the NAME of the receiver with receiver id 2 and on clicking the name I want to fetch conversation between these two users.

similarly, in the receiver dashboard, I want to show the list of all users who have sent a message.

so in short, as a logged-in user, I should see the name of users to whom I have sent a message and from whom I got the messages, and when clicking those names I will able to see all the conversations.

Message.php

class Message extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

}

currently, I am doing like this

```
Route::get('/messages','MessageController@index');

public function index()
    {

        $messages = Message::with('user')
        ->groupBy('sender_id')
        ->where('receiver_id',auth()->user()->id)
        ->orWhere('sender_id',auth()->user()->id)
       
        ->get();
}
```

and my vue is like this

```
<li v-for="(person,index) in users" :key="index">
                    <a href="" @click.prevent="showMessage(person.user_id)">{{person.user.name}}{{person.user_id}}</a>
                    
                    </li>

export default{
        data(){
            return{
                users:[],
                messages:[],
                
                
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            axios.get('/api/users').then((response)=>{
                this.users = response.data
            })
        }
//....

        
        
    }
```

my problem is: if I (let's say john )sent a message to David(receiver), I see John name on David dashboard which is correct so on clicking John name I can fetch all the conversation between John and David However, On john's dashboard(message sender to David) I see John's name, but I need here David's name.

so on the sender dashboard, I need the receiver name and on the receiver dashboard, I need sender name.

I think this probably related to the query. please help me. Thanks

Comment: since `sender_id`, and `receiver_id` are both `id` on `users` table, you might need to revisit relationship definition in the model. You might want to define two relationships for sender and receiver and identify them using their column names.